# How to show a popup calendar in Ajaxpopup box?

Tags: asp.net, calendar, modalpopupextender

I have an application and I am using ModalPopupExtender to edit some information and one of the information is date of birth.
I'm using a Westwind calendar in my project, but the calendar is not opening when I try to use it.

Can someone tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: it will help in solving your problem if you post some relevant code.

Comment: what is an "Ajaxpopup box"? can you give a link to the control please?

Comment: It is ModalPopupExtender what code do u want Westwind is a simple calender it is free online and when u click on it, It open up a calender

Comment: Did not find the exact reference for the Westwind calendar, could you provide a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it with the [AjaxControlToolkit Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/calendar/calendar.aspx) instead of the Westwind calendar.